# Flask runs python script with "OnClick": False positive activation

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my app.py I added a python fuction (to track events) like this:

```py
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals.update(track_event=track_event)

def track_event(category, label, action):
   do="something"
```

In my HTML code I added it like this:

```
<a href="somewebsite.web" 
       class="button button-rounded tright button-large topmargin-sm"
       onclick="{{ track_event(category='outbound',action='stackoverflow', 
       label='somewebsite.web') }}"
>
```

On this side I offer a listing and therefore add this kind of HTML snipped several times with different URLS (instead of somewebsite.web).

Here is my problem: Instead of being activated "onclick", everytime I load the website all of the onclick events are immediately activated once the browser finished loading.

The functions works as expected, but it shouldnt be called unless someone actually clicks on the . Did anyone have a similar experience?

Is my error in Python or HTML?

Comment: What does that part of the rendered template look like?

Comment: interesting, havent checked that before:
```
<a href="somewebsite.web" 
       class="button button-rounded tright button-large topmargin-sm"
       onclick="None"
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned that, in the rendered HTML, you had `onclick="None"`. The problem is that your function

```py
def track_event(category, label, action):
    do="something"
```

doesn't return anything. Jinja is going to do what you tell it to do and put the return value of that function in the template. If you `return None` (which is implicit: if you never explicitly return, you `return None` by default).

Comment: Thanks, I understand now that I wrongly understood how flask/jinja and HTML were working on this. I wanted to activated the function itself "on click".

Ill have to use JS or Ajax for what I need then. Thank you